# Azure Functions not Sending Email or Printing Console Log

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have create a Function App at Azure Painel. Then my function project looks like this

**local.settings.json**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=...",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=...",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  }
}
```

**host.json**

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "functionTimeout": "00:10:00",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "debugOnly",
    "logLevel": {
      "Function": "Trace",
      "default": "Trace"
    },
    "console": {
      "isEnabled": "true"
    }
  }
}
```

**MyFunction.cs**

```
[FunctionName("MyFunction")]
public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 0 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)]TimerInfo ti, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"Timer trigger function started at: {DateTime.Now}");
    var lib = new MyLibJobs();
    await lib.Run();
    log.LogInformation($"Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
}
```

```
public async Task Run()
{
    var logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.Console().CreateLogger();
    logger.Information("=== === === === === === === === === === === === === === ===");
    logger.Information("shometing");
    ElasticEmail.Send(...);
    ...
}
```

When I run the function, I'm able to get the first log. But after that nothing more seems to work (running locally all works). Inside `MyLibJobs` I have `LoggerConfiguration` and `ElasticEmail` but none of this seems to be called. No console logs or no emails been sent.

What could I be missing here?

Comment: put the code of MyLibJobs

Comment: also, rather than a ILogger into MyLibJobs, you should pass your current ILogger:  var lib = new MyLibJobs(log);

Comment: Hi, does my solution work?

Answer (score 0):

change the code to receive ILogger in the constructor, it will print the errors. About the messages I do believe it's throwing and exception, which you also be able to catch using the provided code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public class MyLibJobs
{
    private ILogger _log;
    public MyLibJobs(ILogger log)
    {
        _log = _log;
    }

    public async Task Run()
    {
        _log.Information("=== === === === === === === === === === === === === === ===");
        _log.Information("shometing");

        try
        {
            ElasticEmail.Send(...);     
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            _log.LogError(ex, "error when trying to send email);
            throw;
        }       
    }
}   

[FunctionName("MyFunction")]
public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)]TimerInfo ti, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"Timer trigger function started at: {DateTime.Now}");
    var lib = new MyLibJobs(log);
    await lib.Run();
    log.LogInformation($"Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
}
```

Comment: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host Cannot bind parameter type ILogger

Comment: you need to import using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

Comment: still got nothing, the first log works but that all, not even Exception.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

If you want to use EMAIL on Azure Web App, the only way is via an SMTP relay. The third party service such as [SendGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-sendgrid?tabs=csharp) provides these type of services.

**Original Answer:**

Is this what you want?

[image]

This is mycode:

**Function1.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Serilog;
using ILogger = Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger;

namespace ConsoleLogFunction
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        public class MyLibJobs
        {
            public async Task Run()
            {
                var logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.Console().CreateLogger();
                logger.Information("=== === === === === === === === === === === === === === ===");
                logger.Information("shometing");
            }
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("*/1 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"Timer trigger function started at: {DateTime.Now}");
            var lib = new MyLibJobs();
            await lib.Run();
            log.LogInformation($"Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        }
    }
}
```

**host.json:**

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "functionTimeout": "00:10:00",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "debugOnly",
    "logLevel": {
      "Function": "Information",
      "default": "Trace"
    },
    "console": {
      "isEnabled": "true"
    }
  }
}
```

please note that you close the information level.

Comment: Still got no log when it enter on `await lib.Run()`, not even exception.

Comment: unfortunately not, as I said when it goes to internal lib seems that nothing happens. I have a WebJob that do the same thing, and there it's working. But not with Functions.

Comment: https://imgur.com/SC76nPf, after `starting...` it should take some time... where I download a csv file. And `starting...` it's from inside lib.run()

Comment: @Pablo Use sendGrid to send emails: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-sendgrid?tabs=csharp

Comment: @Pablo Please note that use email on Azure Web App needs SMTP relay. You can only choose to use a third party or transfer. There is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

Okay... It seems that the main problem it wasn't with the log or email, well maybe with the log (a little), but not with the email.

Because I had the same code running on Azure WebJob (and working), I thought that it should be working in the same way with Azure Functions (which seems not). That's why my question was focused on logs and email, but the issue could be related to something else.

1. Indeed serilog seems to not work on Azure Functions. So it makes the Thiago Custodio answer right. I should be using `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`.
2. During the program steps, to trigger the email, something else should be done, where I'll explain

The program basically do the follow steps:

- a. log that it started
- b. download some csv data
- c. write these csv data into a csv file
- d. read the csv file, compare with another one and write another csv file
- e. send the csv file diff to another api
- f. finally send email with the summary about what was done

Doing some researches, I read that `Path.GetTempPath()` changes accordingly the function runs. That said I think that this could be the main the problem. I just don't know what exactly because I have never got an error, the Functions just ran like no tomorrow.

To workaround this, I decide to write my files inside `"D:\home\data\temp"`. There I can see my files and all steps are running correctly.

I can't say that this is the write answer. But it's the one that worked for me.